# Xcode, static libraries and headers

Tags: ios, xcode

I know this question has been asked several times. I have read many questions and the accepted answers: no one works for me.

I have this problem within these settings:

- one project LIB created and compiled as 'static library' for iOS
- one project APP created as an empty app that links against the LIB project
- the LIB project is used as a 'subproject' within the APP project.

I created everything for the second time from scratch following the instructions (step by step) available at: [apple doc - static libraries](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH1-SW1).

The project APP compiles fine. The linker finds the static library. I can even use the classes defined in LIB when building a Storyboard, but APP cannot find the single `.h` file exported by LIB.

In the previous attempt I modified all of the variables found in previous questions and answers (SRCROOT, etc.) but none worked.

So the question: is there anyone who found a way to find the headers starting from the instructions provided by Apple themselves?

If I were not loosing days for finding some stupid header files, I would consider hilarious that such a simple task (for which Apple wrote two pages of documentation) is so hard to do.

I am using XCode 5.1.1 on OS X 10.9.2.

---

I have created a zipped tar archive containing two XCode projects (a static library and an app) that mimics what I described above. The two projects can be downloaded from the following address: http://www.freefilehosting.net/teststaticlib.

The projects have been created according to the Apple instructions for using static libraries as subprojects.

Comment: In "build phases" under "copy files" should be all the headers your library should export. As shown in the documentation you can select the path where this headers are copied to... So are the headers there or not? Is it you that can not find them or your application?

Comment: Have you considered creating an Xcode Workspace and including both projects?  You might also need to modify the *Header/Library Search Path* of the App project.

Comment: The "Build Phases"/"Copy files" is set as indicated by Apple. The path is the one specified in the documentation. The headers are in the 'build' directory, with the 'include/LIB/" subfolders as expected. As I said I respected every single step indicated by Apple. I did not create a Workspace (may be I will try) but since there are very clear instructions on how to use a static library as a subproject, I would like to understand what I did wrong (or what Apple wrote by mistake).

Comment: Ok, so did you include the header path in your application? Not in the library. Note this is not the same as output path in the library since this are different projects and exist on different locations. To begin with try locating a header file (not folder) in finder, right click it and select "get info" then copy the absolute path and include it in your application as header search path.

Comment: I did not modify the header path because I read (on the same Apple pages) that "Your library’s headers are automatically included in your application’s header search path, as they are inside the built product directory’s include directory". Just to be more precise: I have no problems in using the library object file and the library header files when the APP project does not use the LIB as a subproject (I just add the .a file and the .h file and modify the linker/compiler search paths properly).

Comment: Well, you misinterpreted! If you create a project and create additional target (which is library) you do not need to include the header search path. If you have another application where you wish to include the library then you most certainly do need to add the header search path. And even if you don't need to it does not mean you should not.

Comment: I am not sure that I misinterpreted the "automatically included" since also the .a file is automagically found (I did not modify the library search path). Furthermore there are no additional targets in the APP project. Anyway, I will give it a try: I need only to understand how to indicate the correct folder for the headers. I think this folder changes, part of its path is "..../DerivedData/LIB-dykhkclhvgpgkwguoyzhmlulpvdl".

Comment: It is not magically included: no headers = no linking = no nothing.

Comment: As I said, the LIB 'works': if I add one class in LIB in the StoryBoard (changing the type of a UIViewController) the app works just fine. However, I have created a (third) very simple project (according to the Apple instructions) and it does not find the header. The projects are available at http://www.freefilehosting.net/teststaticlib.

Comment: you know @trojanfoe (and others) gave you the answer and you are ignoring it because you misunderstood some documentation. you are building a *static* library but seem to be citing information about dynamic libraries.

Comment: @BradAllred There is no information I am citing: there is information I am linking - it's different.

Comment: @AntonioSesto The project you've uploaded works fine and `#import "MySmallLib/MyLibViewController.h"` works, was that supposed to fail ?

Comment: @Jkmn Did you get it working by modifying some settings? That `#import ` fails on every single Xcode installation I tested.

Comment: No, I uncompressed the project, added the `#import` and changed nothing else.

Comment: That's strange. I do not find those headers on three different OS X installations (two 10.9+XCode5.1 and one 10.8+XCode 5.0).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your library is present in "target dependencies" in addition to "Link binary With libraries".

[image: Project setup]

Comment: The library is in the 'target dependencies' as shown by your image (I added this step in order to recompile everything when LIB changes because it is not specified by the Apple instructions - if I remove it nothing changes - as expected). The linker has no problem in using the library: if I use a UIViewController (offered by LIB) in the Storyboard (in the APP project) it works just fine. The problem is that XCode does not find the .h files (actually just one).

Comment: I really don't have much else setup in this project and I have been able to import header from "myLib" ever since I made that change

Comment: "actually just one" is that just one of many or just one of one?

Comment: Is it added to the "copy files" section ?

Comment: Yes, it is..... (the points are there to reach the minimum number of chars for a comment:-) )

Comment: you dont need to copy a static library... thats kinda what makes it a static lib. the problem OP has is locating header files, not linking.

Comment: @BradAllred When I say "copy files" section I meant in the library not the application.

Comment: I know what you meant; its wrong. you dont need to "copy" a static library anywhere. ever. if Xcode knows where the library is it can, and will, link no matter the location.

Comment: I'm just not writing english properly, [Exported headers](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012554-CH2-SW4)

Comment: Yes, the 'copy files' section in the library exports the header file I need to include in the app.